# ZF last inserted id

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

does this code gives me the last inserted id of the record, even on a heavy load page?

```
  db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
  $db->insert($this->_name, $fields_values);
  $idAddress = $db->lastInsertId($this->_name);
```

Regards
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function saveData(array $data) {
    $this->_setName('user');

    // this will return all field name for user table in $field variable
    $fields = $this->info($this->getConstCol());

    // By this foreach loop we will set data in $data array
    foreach ($data as $field => $value) 
    {
        if (!in_array($field, $fields)) 
        {
            unset($data[$field]);
        }
    }
    // It will call insert function of (Zend_Db_Table_Abstract Parent of Zend_Db_Table)
    // It will return $pkData which is primary key for user table

    return $this->insert($data); // It will return last insert ID
 }
```

Comment: could you give me more details about this function? or an example on how to use it ? thx ;)

Answer (score 2):

i am using  this...

```
db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$lastInsertId = $db->insert($this->_name, $fields_values);
```

Comment: Probably the best way to retrieve the id.

Answer (score 1):

The `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::lastInsertId()` method is a proxy to `PDO::lastInsertId()`. According to the documentation:

> PDO::lastInsertId — Returns the ID of the last inserted row or sequence value
>
> **Note:**
>
> This method may not return a meaningful or consistent result across different PDO drivers, because the underlying database may not even support the notion of auto-increment fields or sequences.

Now you know. Use it as your own risk!